# Executing a task programatically Django-Viewflow

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-viewflow

im trying to run a viewflow flow entirely by code. I have succesfully created a task this way but I have failed to execute  the task that follows the creation of the process.

I've tried using de handler aproach given in the oficial view-flow documentation but I don't know how to do it properly.

flows.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from viewflow import flow , Task
from viewflow.base import this, Flow
from viewflow.flow.views import CreateProcessView, UpdateProcessView, CancelProcessView, AssignTaskView, DetailProcessView
from viewflow.lock import select_for_update_lock
from .models import DeliveryProcess, Revisiones
from viewflow import frontend
from . import views
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

@flow.flow_start_func
def create_flow(activation, campos_proceso, **kwargs):
    activation.process.asignador = campos_proceso['asignador']
    activation.process.ejecutor = campos_proceso['ejecutor']
    activation.process.tipo_de_flujo = campos_proceso['tipo_de_flujo']
    activation.process.estado_del_entregable = campos_proceso[
    'estado_del_entregable']
    activation.process.save()
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation


@frontend.register
class Delivery_flow(Flow):
    process_class = DeliveryProcess

    start = flow.StartFunction(create_flow).Next(this.execution_received_handler)

    execution_received_handler = (
            flow.Function(
                this.on_execution_recived,
                task_loader=this.get_shipment_handler_task)
                .Next(this.end)
    )

    ejecutar = (
        flow.View(
            UpdateProcessView,
            ).Assign(lambda act: act.process.ejecutor
            ).Next(this.end)
    )
    end = flow.End()

    @flow.flow_func
    def on_execution_recived(self, activation):
        activation.process.revisor = process_fields['revisor']
        activation.process.save()
        activation.prepare()
        activation.done()

    def get_shipment_handler_task(self, flow_task, ejecutar):
        return Task.objects.get(process=ejecutar.process)
```

views.py

```
from ..Flujo import flows
from datetime import datetime
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Revisiones, DeliveryProcess, Entregable
from viewflow.flow.views import CreateProcessView, UpdateProcessView
from viewflow.decorators import flow_start_view, flow_view
from viewflow.flow.views import StartFlowMixin, FlowViewMixin, UndoTaskView, CancelTaskView, CancelProcessView, AssignTaskView

class ReView(FlowViewMixin, generic.CreateView) :
    model = Revisiones
    fields = ['revisor', 'observaciones_revisor']
    task_description= 'Revision'

def StartProgTask(request):#, campos_entregable):
    campos_entregable = {
    'nombre_entregable': 'Puente Magico',
    'asignador':request.user,
    'observaciones_asignador':'Este es un puente magivo',
    'ejecutor':request.user,
    'url_inicial':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-yNGb0Q91Y',
    'email_ejecutor': 'a@a.com.co',
    'tipo_de_flujo':True,
    'fecha_inicio' :datetime.now(),
    'fecha_final_planeada':datetime.now(),
    'fecha_final_modificada':datetime.now(),
    'fecha_final_real':datetime.now(),
    'estado_del_entregable': True,
    }

    campos_proceso={
        'asignador': campos_entregable['asignador'],
        'ejecutor': campos_entregable['ejecutor'],
        'tipo_de_flujo': campos_entregable['tipo_de_flujo'],
        'estado_del_entregable': campos_entregable['estado_del_entregable'],
    }

    activation = flows.Delivery_flow.start.run(campos_proceso)
    Entregable.objects.crear_entregable(campos_entregable)
    return render(request, "Flujo/landing.html")

def Execute(request): #campos_ejecucion, request):
    campos_ejecucion = {
    'ejecutor':request.user,
    'revisor':request.user,
    # 'entregable': id_entregable, # se recibe en campos_ejecucion
    'observaciones_ejecutor':'Este es un puente magico',
    'url_ejecucion':'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-yNGb0Q91Y',
    }
    campos_proceso = {
    'revisor':campos_ejecucion['revisor']
    }

    flows.Delivery_flow.execution_received_handler.run(flows.Delivery_flow.ejecutar)
    Entregable.objects.crear_entregable(campos_ejecucion)
    return render(request, "Flujo/landing.html")
```

Comment: `Task.objects.get()` will work on model not viewflow imported by `from viewflow import flow , Task` Is that a model you mean to import?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Im following the documentation of the "Function" method from this page. 
https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/django-viewflow-1.2.0/autoapi/nodes/func/index.html

Comment: What you are looking for is default model `Task` in virewflow see [here](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/django-viewflow-1.2.0/autoapi/models/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, that solves the error but I still cant manage to run the task programatically, iv'e eliminated the error part from the question, thank you.

Comment: so what is the error now why cant you run the task?

Comment: What i did was creat a new "task" model and then try to import it. now what happens is this. 'View' object has no attribute 'process'